# Jenkins : Groovy : Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject getProperty java.lang.String

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>
> Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject
>
> getProperty
>
> java.lang.String
> (com.cccis.telematics.build.Templates.run_jgitflow_template)
>
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod
>
> (StaticWhitelist.java:180)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happened here is that the property didn't exist as named on the object in question, so Groovy began introspecting the object looking for it.  I suppose that allowing introspection could lead to security vulnerabilities.

reproduce:

```
class Foo
{
   String FOOSPRoperty
}

def a_method()
{
  Foo f = new Foo()
  f.foosPROPERTY.replace( "x", "y" )
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it seems to be absolutely correct. I had the exact same problem but with `setProperty`, from trying to set a property that I hadn't declared. Once declared, the error went away.

Comment: Wow, if this is the case then the error message is incredibly bad.